# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with WebView

Tags: macos, webkit, swift

I try to make simple OSX application with WebView. I am new in Swift, and have some errors:
it's my WebView delegate file:

```
class WebViewControllerDelegate: NSObject{

@IBOutlet var webview: WebView!

override init()
{
    super.init()
    self.webview.frameLoadDelegate = self
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
    self.webview.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
}

func didFinishLoadForFrame()
{
    println("ok:")
}
```

}

I try to run this, but have EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error at line where I set frameLoadDelegate to self. I think it's error with web view outlet, but i can't fix it.

`self.webview` is nil, and i don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in Xib / Storyboard files are not loaded nor connected during initialization. That is why `self.webview` is nil in your code.

You really should not attach the IBOutlet directly to your "delegate". Instead, connect it to your view controller and have the view controller set it on the delegate. You should do that in `viewDidLoad` because that is when you can guarantee all of the objects have been created and connected.

Comment: I connect FrameLoadDelegate to this class, but viewDidLoad() not run after application start. It's OSX application, maybe it can be important

Comment: @user2176752 I didn't notice that this was an NSObject subclass. viewDidLoad will not work then. See my update.

Comment: @drewag could you explain how to delegate properly through the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error before. I give you a suggestion for solve this error. Do following things...
1. Click on the View Controller open the connection inspector.
See this...[image]
2. And then you have to double check on the connection inspector window and find something contain like following image... [image]
3. Then you have to delete one outlet. According to my one I have to delete below one... finally solved one...[image]

Then run the code...